# Как по chat_id получить ник в telegram?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Как можно зная message.chat.id получить имя пользователя?
Например у меня есть id чата и мне необходимо получить имя пользователя из этого чата.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по вашему комментарию у Вас уже есть модель **message**

Вся информация о пользователе (имя пользователя, идентификатор, имя/фамилия и фотографии профиля) доступна из объекта [Telegram.User](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/latest/telegram.html#telegram.User) . Вы можете легко получить его с помощью [Telegram.Message](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.message.html?highlight=message)

```
user = update.message.from_user
```

Comment: а можно с помощью этого например по чат айди 145543 узнать имя пользователя?

Comment: Судя по вашему комментарию у Вас уже есть модель message.

Если ваш бот получил сообщения от этого пользователя, то ваша учетная запись пользователя сможет просматривать его профиль или личное сообщение с ним.

Но, если нет. то к сожалению, аккаунт бота пока не может инициировать чат

Comment: Спасибо за совет! У меня в базе есть только chat id поэтому я не смогу получить имя

Comment: Пожалуйста, если ответ Вам помог и больше вопросов нет, нажмите галочку рядом с ответом :)